# probability that a random point in the real space lies inside a convex polytope

Tags: probability, area, convex-geometry, polytopes

I have a convex polytope obtained by the intersection of set of halfspaces. Is there any way to find the probability that a random point on real space lies inside the convex polytope. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "a random point in the real space"?

Comment: I apologize, it's any point in the 2-dimensional real space.

Comment: Are all points equally likely to be drawn?

Comment: Yes they are equally likely.

Comment: If the polytope has finite area, any point has probability $0$ of being inside.

Answer (score 1):

There is no uniform distribution on $\mathbb R^2$; see [Uniform distribution on $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87443/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the following slightly changed setup: *What is the probability of a random point from some encasing hypercube (of finite size!) to also fall inside your convex polytope?*

Then it becomes quite easy. Simply calculate the hypervolume $V$ of your convex polytope, calculate the hypervolume $V_0$ of the hypercube, and get the searched for probability $P$ by
$$P=\frac{V}{V_0}$$
--- rk