# Selecting a random number from $(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, intuition, infinity, random

A random number $a$ is selected from $(0,1) \cup  (1,\infty)$.

Let $A $ be the event that (a random number from $(0,1) \cup  (1,\infty))$ $ \in (0,1)$. Let $P(A) = x$

Let $B$ be the event such that (a random number from $(0,1) \cup  (1,\infty))$ $ \in (1,\infty)$.Therefore, $P(B)=1-x$

Now, let $b = \frac{1}{a}.$ Since, a is random, b is random.

If $a \in (0,1)$(Probablity is $x$)  then $b \in (0,1)$(Probablity is $1-x$)

Therefore, $x = 1-x.$
Therefore, $x = \frac12$ which is definitely not right.

What is going wrong?

Comment: "*A random number is selected from $(0,1)\cup (1,\infty)$*"  How?  According to what distribution?  Uniformly at random is not a possibility.  Until you clarify this your question is unanswerable and meaningless.

Comment: @JMoravitz Uniform distribution.

Comment: Your errors are due to your callous handling of randomness. You can't just "randomly" pick a number in a set. For example, there is no uniform distribution on the rationals.

Comment: @Boomerang There does not exist a uniform distribution on an unbounded set of real numbers.  Try again.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. Got it now. Should I delete the question then?

Comment: @Boomerang, no, you can keep it up. it might help someone else.

Comment: See [is there a uniform distribution over the real line?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85955/is-there-a-uniform-distribution-over-the-real-line)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the link.

Comment: Your argument is ok until you assume that $x=1-x$. I think you assume that $b$ has the same law as $a$, which is not always true if $b = 1/a$ (the law of $b$ is uniquely determined by the law of $a$ and $b = 1/a$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the comments are correct that you cannot pick a random number "uniformly" from a set of infinite length, that is not the real problem here. Let's make a few changes to get the same situation:

Pick a point from $(0,1)\cup (1,4)$ with uniform distribution. This is possible on this set. There will be a probability of $\frac 14$ that the point is in $(0,1)$ and of $\frac 34$ that the point is in $(1,4)$.

Now define the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}3x+1, &\quad x \in (0,1)\\\dfrac{4-x}3,&\quad x\in (1,4)\end{cases}$$

and define $b = f(a)$ similar to how you defined $b = \frac 1a$. Just as in your case $b$ will be in $(1,4)$ if and only if $a \in (0,1)$.

If we pick $a$ uniformly at random, then $P(a \in (0,1)) = \frac 14, P(a \in (1,4)) = \frac 34$.

So $P(b \in (0,1)) = \frac 34, P(b \in (1,4)) = \frac 14$.

And here is your mistake:

> Since, a is random, b is random.

You assumed that since the probability of picking a number in $(0,1)$ is $\frac 14$, that $P(b \in (0,1))$ must also be $\frac 14$.

But this is false, because you did not pick $b$ at random by the same method as picking $a$. $a$ was picked per the indicated distribution. Because of the functional dependence on $a$, $b$ is picked by a different probability distribution. Its odds of being in a given range are different from the odds for $a$ to be in that same range.